# Riving knife options for table saws which came with splitters?

Tags: table-saw

Many older table saws came equipped with a splitter, which is not as [safe as a riving knife](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-prevent-dangerous-kickback-on-a-table-saw). I have one such saw, a Powermatic 64, but there are many others.

What are some options for equipping a riving knife on to a table saw which came with a splitter, but not a riving knife?

Comment: Unfortunately shopping advice isn't a good fit for the Stack Exchange format, but you may be able to salvage your question if you can reframe it without asking for a purchasing recommendation.

Comment: If I ask which ones are known to fit, will that work?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Making the question more generic and asking for riving knife options for any saw that came with a splitter would be even better. Either way, you can still mention which options you've looked at already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since 2009, every new saw sold in the US is required to include a riving knife. However, prior to 2009, many saws had traditional splitters which are not as effective at preventing kickback as riving knives, as discussed in [What is the difference between a riving knife and a splitter on a table saw?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/1013/49) (which you also referenced in your question).

If you do have an older saw, your options will vary based on the popularity of your saw, but there are at least a couple commercially-available aftermarket riving knife options on the market; for example:

- [BORK](http://www.theborkstore.com/) (Bolt-On Ripping Knife)
- [Shark Guard](http://www.thesharkguard.com/sharksplitter.php)

You also mentioned these in the original version of your question, and I haven't run across any other commercially-available aftermarket riving knives that I recall.

In addition to commercially-available options, some people have also crafted their own custom riving knives for their older saws.

- http://workshop.electronsmith.com/content/making-my-own-riving-knife/
- http://www.garymkatz.com/ToolReviews/riving_knife.html - In this example, it looks like the saw basically had support for a riving knife already but probably only included a riving knife-style splitter with a permanently-attached blade guard. Many saws sold today include either a standalone riving knife and separate riving knife-style splitter with integrated blade guard and anti-kickback pawls, or a convertible riving knife with a blade guard and anti-kickback pawls which can both be easily added and removed.

Based on one [article](http://ggober.com/shop/p66splitter.htm) I found, it seems the design of the arbor assembly on the original Powermatic 66 cannot be modified to accommodate a true riving knife, which raises, lowers, and tilts with the blade. If you cannot retrofit a riving knife on your older saw, there is a less convenient but somewhat viable workaround. This involves making several zero-clearance throat plates, each with an integrated splitter at a different location based on the hight of the saw blade. In addition to custom solutions, there is at least one commercially-manufactured option.

- [Woodcraft Magazine](http://www.woodcraftmagazine.com/FreeStuff/Table_Saw_Safety.pdf) article on table saw safety (includes instructions for making a custom throat plate splitter)
- [MicroJig MJ Splitter](http://www.microjig.com/products/mj-splitter/)

The obvious downside is that you basically need a separate throat plate for roughly each height you want to cut, and even then you can only handle cuts with the blade set to 90 degrees. Perhaps you could also make custom integrated splitter throat plates for other angles, but it may not be practical or advisable. MicroJig's MJ Splitter is only designed for [90 degree cuts](http://www.microjig.com/information_center/slideshows/mj-splitter/mj-splitter-beforebuy.shtml#7).